# crear un tablero (con programación orientada a objetos) en python

Tags: python

Estimados, necesito hacer un tablero (para el juego de la serpiente y la escalera) con en el que pueda contar la posición que avanzan los jugadores a medida que se tira un dado y ver lo que ocurre a medida que avanzan, si tienen que retroceder o avanzar más. Como puedo seguir??, les dejo el código que tengo:

```
   import random
   n=int(input("ingrese numero de filas: "))
   m=int(input("ingrese numero de columnas: "))
   b=int(random.randint(1,6))
   q=int(input("ingrese el numero de escaleras que quiere: "))
   w=int(input("ingrese el numero de serpientes que quiere: "))

   def tablero():
      lista = []
      for i in range((n*m)+1):
         i+=0
         lista.append(i)
      return lista 
   algo=tablero()
   print(algo)
   u=int(input("ingrese numero de jugadores: "))    
   def jugadores():
      nombres = []
      for nombre in range(1,u+1):
        g=raw_input("Nombre jugador"+" "+str(nombre)+": ")
        print(g)
        nombres.append(g)
      return nombres 
   nl=jugadores()
   print(nl)
   def casillas_serpiente(w):
     c_s=[]
     i=0
     while i < w :
         g=int(random.randint(1,(n*m)))
         if g not in c_s:
            i+=1
            c_s.append(g)
         return(c_s)
     vu=serpiente(w)
    def casillas_escalera(q,vu):
     c_e=[]
     i=0
     while i < q :
        h=int(random.randint(1,(n*m)+1))
         if h not in c_e and h not in vu:
            i+=1
            c_e.append(h)
       return(c_e)
    ju=escalera(q,vu)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo falla el código que compartes? ¿Recibes algún error o estás atascado en algún problema?

Comment: no, no recibo ningún error, es solo que necesito saber como poder seguir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para, literalmente, contestar tu pregunta, estas son las cosas que deberias hacer para poder seguir:

- Ya que tienes una lista `nl` con el nombre de los jugadores, debes crear una funcion que empiece a dar turnos a los jugadores y que lleve el registro de en que posicion va cada jugador, lo cual no sera dificil porque en la variable `algo` ya tienes almacenado el tablero en una lista. Esta funcion deberia tener un ciclo infinito hasta dar con la condicion de que un jugador a llegado al final del tablero.
- Debes hacer una funcion o incluir una instruccion junto con el turno del jugador,  que simule "tirar" el o los dados. Esto es facil porque ya tienes importada la libreria `random`, y al parecer ya sabes usarla muy bien, o por lo menos para este caso. Sera tan facil como hacer un `random.randint`
- Debes hacer una funcion que compare las dos listas: de serpientes y escaleras con la posicion en donde esta el jugador. Para tal efecto puedes usar la funcion de python `zip` en conjunto con otro elemento iterativo simple.
- Debes hacer una funcion o incluir la instruccion dentro de otra funcion para cambiar la posicion del jugador segun le toque escaleras o serpientes.

De acuerdo con las reglas del juego, estas son las cosas que debes hacer para poder seguir.